# CakePHPのサニタイズの代わりに使えるおすすめのライブラリは?

Tags: php

CakePHPのSanitizeが廃止になるそうなので、代わりにネイティブPHPで使えるライブラリを探しています。

今までCakePHPしか触ったことがないので、何が定番で信用できるのかわからないので教えて下さい。

Comment: 該当の質問は[「Xの一覧が知りたい」という質問の傾向と他サイトでの対応](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1381/x%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7%E3%81%8C%E7%9F%A5%E3%82%8A%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%AE%E5%82%BE%E5%90%91%E3%81%A8%E4%BB%96%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E5%AF%BE%E5%BF%9C)にあるリスト質問になってしまうかと思います。
もう少し範囲を絞って質問するなどの工夫が必要ではないでしょうか。 本来ならコメントに記載したかったのですが、評価点が足りない為回答へのコメントとなりますことをご了承ください。

Answer (score 1):

`Sanitize::html()`の代わりに、PHP標準の`htmlspecialchars()`が使えます。タグの除去であれば、`stripTags()`という同名の関数がこれもPHP標準で存在します。

`escape()`ですが、もし使っていたとしたら、それはSQLを文字列で組み立てているか、さもなくばエスケープが不要な場面で誤って不必要なエスケープをしているということです。滅多なことでは`escape()`が必要になる場面はありません。それを理解して使っているのでない限り、使い方が間違っています。

どう間違っているかわからない、または、Sanitizeの別の関数`clean()`を使っていたら、なぜエスケープが必要なのか、というところをおさらいされた方が良いでしょう。「体系的に学ぶ安全なWebアプリケーションの作り方」という本を紹介しますので、通読されることをおすすめします。

残りの関数は簡単な文字列置換なので、必要なら自力で実装できるでしょう。